# Texturing spherical terrain, seemingly arbitrary distortion

Tags: textures, coordinates, uv-mapping, sphere

I'm using this algorithm to find texture coordinates on a sphere: 
[Wikipedia UV Coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping)

I get the famous seam due to the wrong interpolation, but I also get odd distortions on certain points on the sphere. A picture follows where you can see like five starshaped distortions.

[image]

What could cause this?

Comment: Depending on how your UVs are calculated, if your UV coordinate goes beyond the range of [0 1], then maybe there is a modulo so a value of 1.01 becomes 0.01. Then from one polygon to the next you have the whole texture scrunched up and backwards along one, or both, axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me some time, but I finally found the problem. In the wiki entry is written that the unit vector is needed. I basically forgot to normalize the vector before the calculation!